# vaadin combobox suggestion popup displays outside of vaadin window in liferay

Tags: liferay, vaadin, vaadin7

I have a vaadin-liferay portlet. I am using vaadin Window component which is having vertical scroll as it has more content inside. A combobox is added inside the window. But when the combobox suggestion popup opened its position is changed according to the browser scroll not according to vaadin window scroll. Please help

Comment: Would you be able to provide a screenshot? It's hard (at least for me) to visualize your problem.

Comment: Please provide *code and* a screenshot. Otherwise there's just no possibility to help.